# How to save a filtered subset in R in a new column?

Tags: r, filter, data-manipulation, dplyr

I hava a large `dataframe`, and I want to filter based on some columns (all factors), and save the filtered rows as a new column in the same `dataframe`. So I don't want to make a subset or delete rows, I want to keep them al in the same `dataframe`. 
Example:

```
## my dataframe: 
test <- data.frame(name=c("alice", "brandon", "cedric", "dwayne"), mark = c("V", "R", "R", "R"), test3 = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no"))

## the filter I use for selecting
test %>% filter(mark == "R" & test3 == "no")

## what I want as added new column (filtered selection)
test$conclusion <- c(NA, "yes", NA, "yes")
tets$conclusion <- c(0,1,0,1) # would also be fine.
```

But I don't know how to do this, except for making an new `dataframe` from the filtered results, add a new column, and merge the new `dataframe` with the old `dataframe`. There must be an easier solution. I tried mutate, but I can only calculate a new column with that function. I tried

```
test %>% filter(mark == "R" & test3 == "no") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(.$conclusion == "yes")
```

But then I get this error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `.$conclusion == "yes"` must be length 4 (the number of rows) or one, not 0.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R -

```
test$conclusion <- ifelse(test$mark == "R" & test$test3 == "no", 1, 0)
```

With `dplyr` -

```
test %>%
  mutate(conclusion = ifelse(mark == "R" & test3 == "no", 1, 0))
```

Comment: Note that `as.integer(test$mark == "R" & test$test3 == "no")` is enough